# Создание дерева каталогов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как создать дерево каталогов название которых будут указываться в массиве `s=[1,2,3]`

```
Название дерева test:
  название каталога 1
  название каталога 2
  название каталога 3
```

нужно чтобы в заданном  массиве s в котором расписаны название папок из этого формируется дерево test внутри которого расписано все что храниться в s  и при нажатии на определены каталог происходило конкретное действие
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А название дерева какое? S?

Comment: @pinguin Нет `s`  это просто переменная которая хранит название подкаталогов название дерева допустим test

Comment: То есть вам тупо нужно создать в заданной папке несколько подпапок с именами из списка?

Comment: @Александр ну мне нужно чтобы вот задаётся так сказать массив s в котором раписаны название папок из этого формируется дерево test внутри которого расписано все что храниться в s ну естественно чтобы это в PYQt отображалось и при нажатии на определеный каталог происходило конкретное действие

Comment: связанный вопрос [how to create folder view in pyqt inside main window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5144830/4279)

Comment: @jfs мне вот нужно что то подобное как в примере только чтобы данные в дереве были не из системы а сам добавлял т.е. в массиве есть данные он их записывает в дерево

Comment: @jfs обновил добавил картинку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

порыскав [в интернете нашел фрагмент кода](http://python.su/forum/topic/21625/) который мне нужен был примерно так он должен был бы выглядеть

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
items = ['название каталога 1', 'название каталога 2', 'название каталога 3']
def on_item_expanded(item):
    if item.childCount():
       return
    for i in range(3):
        j=i
        text =j+1
        text=str(text)
        tree_item = QTreeWidgetItem(item, [text])
treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
for item in items:
    root = QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget, [item])
    root.setChildIndicatorPolicy(QTreeWidgetItem.ShowIndicator)
treeWidget.itemExpanded.connect(on_item_expanded)
treeWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: screenshot with GUI with tree]